# Base URL wrongly given in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Ive entered the base URL wrongly in the backend and now everything loads bad. Ive tried to change it again in the backend but because the URL ist wrong, the backend also looks messed up. Is there any file where I can change it directly with a text editor? Thanks!

Comment: Can you not fight your way to the right page even if it looks messed up? It's either that, or changing the record in the `wp_options` table in the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has worked for me in the past: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL